# Using Adobe ExtendScript (Ext JS) to read a variable and rotate a shape

Tags: javascript, vb.net, extjs, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm using the variables panel in Illustrator to pull a data set I've got.

For example there's 2 text variables and 1 number going from 0-359. I'm looking for a script which looks at the variable name and pulls the number, then uses that number to rotate a shape by that many degrees.

I have no experience in ExtJS, but this looks like it could be done?

Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks for any help.
Dave

Answer (score 0):

I didn't play with variables in the UI but I can read both variables object and rotate method on pageItem are available so the recipe seems feasible.

Drop a line at the Illustrator Scripting Forum. One may have worked on that kind of stuff ;)